# Allow Spacer() to shrink to maintain text position

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view laid out like this:

```
Text
Spacer
Rectangle
Spacer
```

I'm trying to make the position of the `Rectangle` remain constant *unless* the Text is close enough to push it down. But currently, if the text grows a line taller, the rectangle moves down.

```swift
VStack {
    Text("Hello")
    Spacer()
    Rectangle()
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    Spacer()
}
```

I tried making the `Spacer` layoutPriority lower than the Text and Rectangle to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

If your view can have a fixed height, you could set a max height for the lower `Spacer()` and set higher `LayoutPriority()` for the `Text` and `Rectangle`.

Here is an example:

```
 VStack {
        Text("Make this text longer and longer")
            .layoutPriority(1)
        Spacer()
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .layoutPriority(1)
        Spacer()
            .frame(maxHeight: 120)
 }
 .frame(width: 100, height: 300)
```

Now, if you make the text longer it will grow in height and push the rectangle down as soon as the text touches it. I hope it helps.

Comment: I _might_ be able to make it fixed using a GeometryReader to get the window size, not sure, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question clearly, but it looks like what you need.

```
    VStack {
        Text(
            "Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World "
        )
        .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .padding(.vertical, 100)
    }
```

Comment: That's closer to what I want, but I want the rectangle to be almost centred, and manually specifying padding like that won't scale well